# After updating to Xcode 12.0 React-Native build failed

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I have updated Xcode to 12.0 in order to test React Native project on iOS 14.0.
When I build the project I'm getting the following error. I tried Excluding arm64 architecture from Debug, tried removing bitcode from debug.

> in
> ~/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o),
> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file
> (~/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o))
> built for iOS, file
> '~/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a'
> for architecture arm64

Comment: how did you solve it ?

Comment: how did you solve it ?